# When cell from range A exists in Range B then copy both into rows below tables

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have two small tables.

First one contains 3 columns and 5 rows. Second one contains 4 columns and 5 rows.

When cell value from first table (column 3) is equal to cell value from second (table column 3,4) then I need to copy ID's of those cells (columns 1 both tables) let say 10 rows below so I get another small tables where I would see all ID's from both tables which are equal.

I could do that with IF statement but It's lot of job and I'm looking for better solution.

I developed that simply code but I need to repeat it again and again...

```
Sub test()

    If Range("C6").Value = Range("G6").Value Then
        Range("B6").Copy
        Range("B20").PasteSpecial
        Range("F6").Copy
        Range("C20").PasteSpecial
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Edit

I have duplicates in table A and I want that if for example value ROL appears two times in table its ID should be copied two times as well.

```
Dim cl As Range 

For Each cl In Range("C6:C15")
    If cl.Value = "CHEM" Then
        cl.Offset(0, 2).Copy
        Range("B25").PasteSpecial
        Range("C25").Value = 1
    End If
    If cl.Value = "ROL" Then
        cl.Offset(0, 2).Copy
        Range("B26").PasteSpecial
        Range("C26").Value = 2 
    End If 
Next
```

What you wrote is exactly what I need to do. I tried to finish code given by you but I do something wrong. Once both values match I need copy their ID's and paste into the cells B25 and C25 next to B26 and C26 etc. Look at the code below please. I get error message with cla.Offset(0,-2).Copy (Application defined or object defined). How can I paste here the code as it looks like you did it? –

```
Dim cla As Range
Dim clb As Range

For Each cla In Range("A6:C15") 'first range of values
    For Each clb In Range("E7:G13") 'second range of values
        If cla.Value = clb.Value Then
            clb.Offset(0, -2).Copy
            cla.Offset(0, -2).Copy
            Range("B25").PasteSpecial
            Range("C25").PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next
Next
```

So this is how the code looks now. Unfortunately, what is copied is not correct. I will explain.

In range 1 there is value INF with ID 1.
In range 2 there is value INF with ID 3.

Once both values meet then output should be 1,3.
Now is 1,1. Additionally value INF is copied as well (shouldn't be copied).

```
Dim cla As Range
Dim clb As Range

Dim R As Long 'declare variable that will refer to a row value
R = 25        'and initialize R to the first row, where to output pairs when found

For Each cla In Range("A6:C15") 'first range of values
    For Each clb In Range("E7:G13") 'second range of values
        If cla.Value = clb.Value Then
            Cells(R, 2) = cla.Value
            Cells(R, 3) = clb.Value
            R = R + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Here you have two tables.
Below tables you can see what the output should be.

```
Table 1                     Table 2
ID Surname   Lesson type    ID  Lesson name Lesson Type
1  Smith      INF           1    Chemia       CHEM
2  Kowalski   ROL           2    Agro         ROL
3  Smith      FIZ           3    Infor        INF
4  Kowalski   CHEM          4    Fizyka       FIZ
5  Smith      EKON          5    Matem        MAT
6  Kowalski   ROL           6    Ekonom       EKON
7  Smith      ROL           7    Maszyny      FIZ 
8  Kowalski   FIZ
9  Smith      MAT
10 Kowalski   EKON

ID table1 ID table2
   1         3
   2         2
   3         4           
   3         7
   4         1
   5         6
   6         2
```

etc...

Comment: Most likely you could use a loop.

Comment: Yeah, but loop won't work properly with that code.

Comment: Isn't that the reason why [xlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) has been invented?

Comment: No one should do the job for me. What I'm asking is to how to do that faster with variables....

Comment: Use e.g. `For` loops: `For R ... For C ... If Cells(R, C)` in each table to get the values for comparison (and eventual output to the third table).

Comment: @TomBrunberg I developed something but there is one problem. I have duplicates in table A and I want that if for example value ROL appears two times in table its ID should be copied two times as well. 
`Dim cl As Range
For Each cl In Range("C6:C15")
    If cl.Value = "CHEM" Then
        cl.Offset(0, 2).Copy
        Range("B25").PasteSpecial
        Range("C25").Value = 1
    End If
    If cl.Value = "ROL" Then
        cl.Offset(0, 2).Copy
        Range("B26").PasteSpecial
        Range("C26").Value = 2
    End If
Next`

Comment: You're talking about basically doing an `Inner Join` in SQL, aren't you?  Two tables, match on a key, print the matching results and their associated fields to a new row.  If so, I think this can be done with named ranges and ADODB library.  The code is a bit longer, but it's fast and flexible if you want to do SQL-like joins inside a workbook.

Comment: I know how to do that in Access it's easy but I need to do that in VBA.  Tables are small. I can even skip table 2 and insert values directly into VBA code as I presented above but I don't know how to resolve situation with duplicates which I want to copy as well.

Comment: As you see, Hubert, the comments are not very good to communicate code. Therefore, note the "Edit" button beneath the tags of your question. Use that to edit your question and add code and a picture of the data that you have to operate on.

Comment: Ouch! Sorry, I misread the task. I thought the strings should be output. I need to check this later as I'm just on my way out. But please clarify what the ID actually means (how are the ID's and strings connected), and provide an image of the data.

Comment: Ok, will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the intention is not to enter actual values into your code as you show in comments.

Regarding the loop(s) arrangement, consider to read one value from table A, then check that value against every value in table B. Then again read next value from A, and check again against all values in B and so on... This requires that the loops are nested

```
For Each cla In Range("A6:C10") 'first range of values
    For Each clb In Range("E6:H10") 'second range of values
        If cla.Value = clb.Value Then
            'hit found, copy (or move) values to output area,
            'increment output area line number
        End If
    Next
Next
```

When a match is found, copy (or move if that is your task) the value(s) to the output area. Continue looping until the last item of both A and B.

---

Addition

You do know how to refer to cells with the `Range()` object. Another way is to use `Cells()`:  `Cells(Row, Column)` where `Row` and `Column` are expressions resolving to numeric values. This is handy when you need to refer to row or column with indices.

So, if your output area is in columns B and C starting on row 25, you can do, before the `For` loop(s):

```
Dim R As Long 'declare variable that will refer to a row value
R = 25        'and initialize R to the first row, where to output pairs when found
```

In the code between `If cla.Value = clb.Value Then` and `End If` remove what you currently have and add ...

```
            Cells(R, 2) = cla.Value 
            Cells(R, 3) = clb.Value
            R = R + 1
```

... to copy the values and increment R in preparation for an eventual other match later.

Note that the output columns are constants (2 and 3) as they don't need to change.

---

Final edit:

Ok, now that you posted actual data, I understand your `Offset(0, -2)` additions earlier. That was correct as you needed the `ID` and not the `Lesson type`. It was the `Paste` to a fixed range, that made it not to work as intended. You can completely avoid the `copy - paste` and instead assign the values directly to correct cells.

Anyways, with the following `For` loops and `Lesson type` in columns "C" and "F" I get the result below.

```
For Each cla In Range("C7:C16")
    For Each clb In Range("F7:F13")
        If cla.Value = clb.Value Then
            Cells(R, 2) = cla.Offset(0, -2)
            Cells(R, 3) = clb.Offset(0, -2)
            R = R + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Result in columns 2 and 3 (or B and C)

```
ID table1 ID table2
        1        3
        2        2
        3        4
        3        7
        4        1
        5        6
        6        2
        7        2
        8        4
        8        7
        9        5
       10        6
```

Comment: What you wrote is exactly what I need to do. I tried to finish code given by you but I do something wrong. Once both values match I need copy their ID's and paste into the cells B25 and C25 next to B26  and C26 etc. Look at the code below please. I get error message with cla.Offset(0,-2).Copy (Application defined or object defined).  How can I paste here the code as it looks like you did it?

Comment: `Dim cla As Range
Dim clb As Range

For Each cla In Range("A6:C15") 'first range of values
    For Each clb In Range("E7:G13") 'second range of values
        If cla.Value = clb.Value Then
            clb.Offset(0, -2).Copy
            cla.Offset(0, -2).Copy
            Range("B25").PasteSpecial
            Range("C25").PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next
Next`

Comment: @HubertS Did you read my last comment from yesterday beneath your question? It seems not as you do not **edit your question** when you want to post new code. After I see that you have moved your comment above (the one with code), I will add to my answer regarding copying matching values to the output area.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it. Now it should be ok. I missed your comment. Could you please look at the code which I added? I feel that I'm very close to solve my problem thanks to you but as I'm very basic in VBA (started to learn) I'm not able to do some things yet.

Comment: it looks much better but still not in point. You can see above.

Comment: @HubertS I rejected your edit (saying "Thanks ..."), as it was not an edit of my answer to your question. I am of course glad I could help you, and that you showed your appreciation, but here at Stack Overflow we are somewhat reserved when it comes to salutations and gratitude expressions. You can read about it in the [help]. Best way to say thanks, is to upvote answers that help you (when you have earned that privilege) and accepting the correct ones (as you did for my answer, yeah!).